# Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'EarlGrey'

Tags: earlgrey

I tried to run the FunctionalTests that comes packed with the EarlGrey demo project.

I ended up seeing this error. How do I resolve it.[image]

Comment: I'd suggest doing a clean build, or checking if you have modules enabled.

Also, try nuking your Build Folder and then rebuilding.

Comment: Hi, I tried both of your suggestions. No luck yet. Do I need to add the EarlGrey impl file somewhere or was the reference missing?

Comment: Also, did you delete / re-add the EarlGrey CocoaPod?

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: Add `use_frameworks!` to your EarlGrey test target. Does that fix it?